# Get iframe contents on load using live()

Tags: jquery, iframe

I've got a file upload script working with an iframe so the page doesn't have to reload.

I've run into an issue concerning retrieving data *from* the iframe when it's loaded using jQuery's `.live()` event, like this:

```
$("iframe").live("load", function() {
    console.log($(this).contents().find("body").html());
});
```

This event doesn't even fire (I get nothing in Firebug), so how can I go about getting the HTML of an iframe after it's loaded some content from my file upload script? I want to do this so I can get the return state of the PHP script run on the server.

I have to use `.live()` as these elements are dynamically added, meaning the traditional `.load()` won't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From jQuery documentation:

**Note: The .live() and .delegate() methods cannot be used to detect the load event of an iframe. The load event does not correctly bubble up the parent document and the event.target isn't set by Firefox, IE9 or Chrome, which is required to do event delegation.**

http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Can you provide a little more information on what you're trying to do, it should be possible to catch the event but not by using iFrame load.

Comment: Shame on myself for not noticing that. Thank you. What I want to do is detect when the file upload script, ran in the iframe, has finished so I can do something with the data it spits out _into_ the iframe, stuff like "error" -> print an error message, "success" -> print success message.

Comment: Does the page within the iFrame post back to itself or to a different page? I guess what I'm getting at is whether or not the iFrame URL changes as you could possibly monitor changes in this? Do you have a testing URL we can have a look at to get a better idea of what you're doing? Or can you post a bit more of the HTML?

Comment: Well, the iframe starts with no URL parameter, and is then given one by jQuery. I could use a `setInterval()` to detect changes, but I'd rather use native events if possible.

Comment: What about using the native onLoad event of the iFrame itself? So when you generate the iFrame, could specify something similar to <iframe src="http://www..." onLoad="YourFunction();"></iframe> then each time iFrame reloads, YourFunction will be called?

Comment: I've used that now. I wanted to keep everything in the .js file, but it's only one function and at the end of the day, all that matters is that it works.