# Trouble with jQuery ".on()" for future events

Tags: jquery, thickbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get iframe contents on load usign live()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371619/get-iframe-contents-on-load-usign-live)

Getting nothing for this...

```
$('body').on('load','iframe',function() {
    console.log('iframe loaded');
});
```

Tried it with document as well... Any ideas what's wrong here?

I'm trying to trigger events in thickbox, but thickbox loads the iframe after the DOM is ready. I thought that on would work. Didn't get any results from delegate either. Using jQuery 1.7

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the "duplicate" question doesn't cover 'on'. Are you saying that jquery on doesn't work with iframe load either? Note, "on" didn't work with click or any other event. Are there events that can be triggered from iframes?